# What is the name of this part of drawers?

Tags: cabinets, drawers, terminology

I was trying to describe a specific part of a set of drawers in another question, and cannot find the right name for it.

[image]

A photo showing the same part.  Notice not all drawers have these, or they may be spaced out in a reduced number - I have one set where there's a drawer-thingy every two drawers, not between each.

[image]

Given that every part of any item made of wood has some kind of name, I'm positive this does but can't find it.

I don’t believe it’s any of these:

- Shelf - its a useless shelf because you can't put anything on it.
- Front Face - this applies to the whole front that doesn't open.

Maybe:

- Shelf brace?
- Stringer?
- Drawer support?  (incredibly boring!)
- Drawer chinrest?  Perhaps - given

Comment: @grawity I don't freehand when doing carpentry - need all the accuracy I can get :-P

Comment: how did you create that animation?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal it's dead easy - I used GIMP - put a photo on one layer, then drew the red boxes on a second layer.  The trick is to "export" as a gif, and in the options turn on animation, and set the time to something that works.  This looks like 300 ms but 500 ms works good too.   Give it a go.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to this diagram¹ it is a 'mid rail'.

[image]

That's a pretty standard North American term. It's quite likely you would find alternates from the UK, Europe, etc. I once worked alongside an architect who was educated in England. This fellow tended to call any horizontal support a [lintel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lintel) although I believe the true definition is a bit stricter.

---

¹ <sub>This diagram seems have at least one typo. 'Gusset or Coner Block' should most likely be 'Gusset or **Corner** Block'.</sub>

Comment: Usually that part is just part of the face frame, but it looks like the ones in your photos are for added rigidity as well.

Comment: That looks like part of the faceframe.  The piece in the question is part of the carcase.

Answer (score 4):

That looks sort of like a [web frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_frame), although only the front rail. A web frame supports the drawer, provides a place to mount the drawer runners, can frame a dust cover, and stiffens the cabinet. From the picture, this looks like it's only there for the last function.

Answer (score 2):

I work at a cabinet shop. The top picture is a face frame cabinet, the name in your diagram is an accurate reflection of what we call it at our shop in the US. The second picture you have is a euro construction cabinet.

We build both and for the euro cabinet we just refer to it as a "drawer stretcher" it's only purpose from what I can tell is to add more strength to the cabinet and keep it more square. Just like stretcher boards would on a face frame cabinet.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: It would help to say the word you mean rather than saying "the name in your diagram".  I am not sure what you mean by that.  On SE, it's possible to  [edit] your answer.

Comment: You mean like a "board stretcher"?